# Spring OAuth2 Generate Access Token per request to the Token Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security

Is it possible to generate multiple valid access tokens using the client_credentials or password grant type per request?

Generating a token using the above grant types only gives a new token when the current one expires per request.

I can use the password grant type to generate a refresh token and then generate multiple access tokens, but doing that will invalidate any previous access tokens.

Any idea how i could change to allow an access token to be generated per request to the  /oauth/token endpoint and insure that any previous tokens are not invalidated?

Below is the XML configuration of my oauth server.

```
<!-- oauth2 config start-->
  <sec:http pattern="/test/oauth/token" create-session="never"
              authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" > 
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/test/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" /> 
    </sec:http>


    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="org.security.oauth2.ClientDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider  ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
          class="org.security.oauth2.CustomUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenServices" 
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300"></property>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate"
           class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oauthdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of having multiple active/valid tokens for an account? I can't think of a valid use case.

Comment: It very useful when you are using OAuth2 for pure client side (JS) web app or mobile app and you'll need difference token for each session. That's what Google done with their APIs

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van this is exactly why i need to generate a new one on each request.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Updated on 21/11/2014

When I double check, I found that `InMemoryTokenStore` use a `OAuth2Authentication`'s hash string as key of serveral `Map`. And when I use same username, client_id, scope.. and I got same `key`. So this may leading to some problem. So I think the old way are deprecated. The following is what I did to avoid the problem.

Create another `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` that can calculate unique key, called `UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator`

```
/*
 * Copyright 2006-2011 the original author or authors.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on
 * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * Basic key generator taking into account the client id, scope, resource ids and username (principal name) if they
 * exist.
 * 
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author thanh
 */
public class UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator implements AuthenticationKeyGenerator {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";

    private static final String SCOPE = "scope";

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    private static final String UUID_KEY = "uuid";

    public String extractKey(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        OAuth2Request authorizationRequest = authentication.getOAuth2Request();
        if (!authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            values.put(USERNAME, authentication.getName());
        }
        values.put(CLIENT_ID, authorizationRequest.getClientId());
        if (authorizationRequest.getScope() != null) {
            values.put(SCOPE, OAuth2Utils.formatParameterList(authorizationRequest.getScope()));
        }
        Map<String, Serializable> extentions = authorizationRequest.getExtensions();
        String uuid = null;
        if (extentions == null) {
            extentions = new HashMap<String, Serializable>(1);
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            extentions.put(UUID_KEY, uuid);
        } else {
            uuid = (String) extentions.get(UUID_KEY);
            if (uuid == null) {
                uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                extentions.put(UUID_KEY, uuid);
            }
        }
        values.put(UUID_KEY, uuid);

        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MD5 algorithm not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }

        try {
            byte[] bytes = digest.digest(values.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, bytes));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("UTF-8 encoding not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, wire them up

```
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="authenticationKeyGenerator">
        <bean class="your.package.UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

## Below way may leading to some problem, see updated answer!!!

<del>You are using DefaultTokenServices. Try this code and make sure to re-define your `tokenServices`

    package com.thanh.backend.oauth2.core;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2RefreshToken;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

    /**
     * @author thanh
     */
    public class SimpleTokenService extends DefaultTokenServices {

        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        private TokenEnhancer accessTokenEnhancer;

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

            OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = createRefreshToken(authentication);;
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = createAccessToken(authentication, refreshToken);
            tokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
            tokenStore.storeRefreshToken(refreshToken, authentication);
            return accessToken;
        }

        private OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication, OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken) {
            DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            int validitySeconds = getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(authentication.getOAuth2Request());
            if (validitySeconds > 0) {
                token.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (validitySeconds * 1000L)));
            }
            token.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
            token.setScope(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getScope());

            return accessTokenEnhancer != null ? accessTokenEnhancer.enhance(token, authentication) : token;
        }

        private ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken createRefreshToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            if (!isSupportRefreshToken(authentication.getOAuth2Request())) {
                return null;
            }
            int validitySeconds = getRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(authentication.getOAuth2Request());
            ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = new DefaultExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (validitySeconds * 1000L)));
            return refreshToken;
        }

        @Override
        public void setTokenEnhancer(TokenEnhancer accessTokenEnhancer) {
            super.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenEnhancer);
            this.accessTokenEnhancer = accessTokenEnhancer;
        }

        @Override
        public void setTokenStore(TokenStore tokenStore) {
            super.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
        }
    }</del>

Comment: This is what i ended up doing and modifying the createAccessToken method to generate a new access token every time it is called, thought there would be a much simpler way without overriding the default classes.

Comment: Hi @JCS, see my updated answer if you found any problem with current modification, thanks!

Comment: i only modified the createAccessToken function, i left the rest of the class untouched with springs default implementation, which seems to be working fine.

Comment: Are there any reasons against generating a new access token per call?

Comment: You will need this in most case. Example: 2 mobile device install same app (mean same client_id, resource_id, scope) and authorize same account. By default, Spring will return same access_token, refresh_token, ... to both device. If one device revoke the access_token, the other device will using an invalid access_token. Especially, If you are using OAuth 2.0 for authentication purpose, you might want each access_token represent an session.

Comment: What I understood from this is, after creating `UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator`, there is no use of `DefaultTokenServices.reuseRefreshToken`. 

Whether we set it to `true` or `false`, we always get new refresh token per request. Am I correct ?

Comment: @AshvinKanani: No. It's only affect when generate `access_token`

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Is it possible to use the same for InMemoryTokenStore instead of JdbcTokenStore???Please reply..

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van getting error for OAuth2Request authorizationRequest = authentication.getOAuth2Request();

Comment: @KJEjava48: Yes, it is possible. Which error did you get? Can you provide exception stack trace or a Gist?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Not runtime error.getOAuth2Request() method is not allowed.Looks like OAuth2Authentication doesn't have this method..

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Oh am using oauth2-1.0.0 RELEASE.That doesn't have this method.This method is allowed in 2.0.4 Release.Can i use getAuthorizationRequest() method instead of getOAuth2Request() ???

Comment: @KJEjava48: Please see this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1.0.x/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator.java

Comment: @KJEjava48: You can use `getAuthorizationRequest()` on 1.0.x

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Now authorizationRequest.getExtensions() is not allowed, Any alternative for that???The link u provided doesn't have that section of uuid

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Any solution??

Comment: @KJEjava48: Sorry, but I have no idea

Comment: I think you can try extents `DefaultAuthorizationRequest` to implement this method. But you need to deal with `OAuth2RequestFactory`

Comment: How did you add items into OAuth2Request.extensions?

Comment: I have followed this approach and it works fine except I am getting multiple tokens in my db and all are valid. What I would like to do is revoke previous token and generate newer one on every request. Is there a way to configure tokenstore like that?

Answer (score 2):

Following @Thanh Nguyen Van approach:

I stumbled upon the same problem while developing my backend with Spring Boot and OAuth2. The problem I encountered was that, if multiple devices shared the same tokens, once one device refreshed the token, the other device would be clueless and, long story short, both devices entered in a token refresh frenzy. My solution was to replace the default `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` with a custom implementation which overrides `DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator` and adds a new parameter `client_instance_id` in the key generator mixture. My mobile clients would then send this parameter which has to be unique across app installs (iOS or Android). This is not a special requirement, since most mobile apps already track the application instance in some form.

```
public class EnhancedAuthenticationKeyGenerator extends DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator {

    public static final String PARAM_CLIENT_INSTANCE_ID = "client_instance_id";

    private static final String KEY_SUPER_KEY = "super_key";
    private static final String KEY_CLIENT_INSTANCE_ID = PARAM_CLIENT_INSTANCE_ID;

    @Override
    public String extractKey(final OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final String superKey = super.extractKey(authentication);

        final OAuth2Request authorizationRequest = authentication.getOAuth2Request();
        final Map<String, String> requestParameters = authorizationRequest.getRequestParameters();

        final String clientInstanceId = requestParameters != null ? requestParameters.get(PARAM_CLIENT_INSTANCE_ID) : null;
        if (clientInstanceId == null || clientInstanceId.length() == 0) {
            return superKey;
        }

        final Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<>(2);
        values.put(KEY_SUPER_KEY, superKey);
        values.put(KEY_CLIENT_INSTANCE_ID, clientInstanceId);

        return generateKey(values);
    }

}
```

which you would then inject in a similar manner:

```
final JdbcTokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(mDataSource);
tokenStore.setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(new EnhancedAuthenticationKeyGenerator());
```

The HTTP request would then look something like this

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: {{host}}
Authorization: Basic {{auth_client_basic}}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username={{username}}&password={{password}}&client_instance_id={{instance_id}}
```

The benefit of using this approach is that, if the client doesn't send a `client_instance_id`, the default key would be generated, and if an instance is provided, the same key is returned every time for the same instance. Also, the key is platform independent. The downside would be that the MD5 digest (used internally) is called two times.

Comment: Was looking for this for a long time. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any scope values at backend side keep empty and at the time of generating access token send sessionId or deviceId or any unique ID to scope , then Always you will get new Token For same client and user combination.