# Implemented Spring OAuth2, getting same access token from different devices

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Implemented Spring OAuth2 security and getting same access token when logging with the same user but from different device. When i logout from any one of these devices(revoke Token)other devices are also getting logged out. Is it a expected behavior or i am missing something ? hoping that sharing the massive code will not help much so kept the question short and simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The default behaviour of the DefaultTokenServices is to re-use existing tokens (based on the behaviour of the existing TokenStore implementations)

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/121797-multiple-valid-oauth-access-tokens-for-same-client

If you want every device to be given different `access_token` then create your own `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` e.g. send your device id on authorization process and let your `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` process that device id to create `access_token` specific for that device.

Answer (score 6):

(Please read `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator` code to put the following solution into context)

`DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator` is available in spring. I just created a custom version with the same code with one extension, i.e., `device_id` sent from the client as a request parameter is retrieved from `OAuth2Authentication` as follows;

`String deviceId = authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("device_id")`

and then is put into the `values` map (used to generate the token finally). Hence the `device_id` becomes a part of the `token` resulting in a unique token per device.

Following is the full solution which is mostly the `DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator` apart from the bit explained above.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationKeyGenerator implements AuthenticationKeyGenerator
{
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";

    private static final String SCOPE = "scope";

    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    @Override
    public String extractKey(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        OAuth2Request authorizationRequest = authentication.getOAuth2Request();
        if (!authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            values.put(USERNAME, authentication.getName());
        }
        values.put(CLIENT_ID, authorizationRequest.getClientId());
        if (authorizationRequest.getScope() != null) {
            values.put(SCOPE, OAuth2Utils.formatParameterList(authorizationRequest.getScope()));
        }

        String deviceId = authorizationRequest.getRequestParameters().get(CustomHeader.device_id.name());
        if(deviceId != null && !deviceId.isEmpty()) {
            values.put("device_id", deviceId);
        }

        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MD5 algorithm not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }

        try {
            byte[] bytes = digest.digest(values.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, bytes));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("UTF-8 encoding not available.  Fatal (should be in the JDK).");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you wire this to TokenStore?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing the same issue can work on the replied solution by MangEngkus, for precise solution you can also refer this link   [Spring OAuth2 Generate Access Token per request to the Token Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020702/spring-oauth2-generate-access-token-per-request-to-the-token-endpoint)