# Spring OAuth2 authorization requests always returning the same access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, access-token, oauth-2.0

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE with OAuth 2.0.7.RELEASE.  I have configured my authorization server to use a JDBC token store (the org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore class) .  However, repeated requests with the same client ID using the grant_type=client_credentials return the same access token, even after server restarts.  The token is valid (it has different expiration dates), but this seems like a security flaw.  How do I make repeated valid requests return different access tokens?  Below is my Spring configuration …

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" request-matcher="regex"
    create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')"
        method="DELETE" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/clients/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/me/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/me" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="marissa" password="koala" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="paul" password="emu" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenEnhancer"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter" />

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="approvalStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" entry-point-ref="entry"
    resource-id="myprojectAssignment" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="entry" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/myprojectassignment" />
</bean>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id=“client”
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        scope="read,write" secret=“password” />
</oauth:client-details-service>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<http pattern="/api/**"  
              create-session="never"
              entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
 <anonymous enabled="false" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                         access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>

 <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                         before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
 <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` for your tokenStore as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020702/spring-oauth2-generate-access-token-per-request-to-the-token-endpoint).