# Spring oauth2 authorization servers always sends the same access token for every request

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have a spring aouth2 authorization server using

- grant_type = client_credentials
- access_token_validity = 300secs.
- Within this time frame, i noticed every request i send with the same 
  **client_id and client_secret** 
  returns the same access token till the token expires.
- Can someone advise how to make the authorization-server generate a new access token for every request including separate access_token_validity time.

Please assist.

Comment: Why you need a new token for every time ?

Comment: I am building a checkout API just like PayPal. To pay for goods and services, a merchant will first have to access my checkout page using the client_I'd and client_secret provided. Multiple users could access one of merchant's site which will intend make a separate request to my checkout api for token access. I expect spring oauth2 to generate separate access token for each user who accesses one of my merchant's site to make any payment. So that access_token_validity(5mins) will be allocated fully to individual users rather than currently where all users share the same access token.

Comment: this link bailed me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020702/spring-oauth2-generate-access-token-per-request-to-the-token-endpoint