# JWT Access Token is not generating on every token authorize calls

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured my Oauth2 Authorization project with JWT. When I authorize using client credentials I gets the access token like as shown below. The expiry time is **43199**

```
{
"access_token":"eyJhbGci........................",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 43199,
"scope": "resource-access",
"jti": "45507f3e-2d8c-4dc8-95ce-295bb690cf3a"
}
```

I am not storing the tokens anywhere like DB or session etc, still If I invoke the same authorize token endpoint I gets the same access token with decreasing expiry time.

Not sure where this token is been stored, what I expect is to get a new token every time I invokes the token authorize endpoint.

Can anyone please help me on this

My custom **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter** class is given below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${scopes}")
    private Boolean checkUserScopes;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory() {
        CustomOauth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new CustomOauth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
        requestFactory.setCheckUserScopes(true);
        return requestFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter tokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, requestFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
        .tokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        if (checkUserScopes) {
            endpoints.requestFactory(requestFactory());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        CustomJwtTokenEnhancerConfig tokenEnhancer = new CustomJwtTokenEnhancerConfig();
        tokenEnhancer.setKeyPair(new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("myjwt.jks"), "password".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return tokenEnhancer;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur Actually I calls the OAuth2 token authorize endpoint from Postman to see whther it is generating new token for each new calls.....but it gives me the same token with decreasing expiry time...

Comment: @dur If I restarts the authorization server then it gives me a fresh new token.........so if it is due to caching, how we can prevent that

Comment: You have to write your own `TokenStore`. You could try to write a subclass of `InMemoryTokenStore`.

Comment: @dur yes I saw one solution over to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020702/spring-oauth2-generate-access-token-per-request-to-the-token-endpoint).....but the problem is there he is using  `JdbcTokenStore` for `authenticationKeyGenerator`. In my case I need `JwtTokenStore` right but it does not have `authenticationKeyGenerator` function

Comment: That is far too broad for Stackoverflow. You have to try to implement your own `TokenStore` and write a new question (with that code), if you get a problem.

Comment: `what I expect is to get a new token every time.. `  that's your assumption. The token may (and imho should) be cached so it is completely legit to get the same existing valid token for the same identity.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Web Token (JWT) authentication technique doesn't require database tables or data stores to keep the generated token. The token is generated by using cryptography algorithms.

When you call your login service, the token is generated by using a payload and a secret value. If your payload is the same, you won't get a new token value with the same secret value.

You can refer to this link for a little more information on how JWT works.
https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec