# Is there a way to receive an additional parameter in the OAuth2 token endpoint?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I'm using [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) in order to implement an OAuth2 Authorization Server. Before switching to this library, I was using Spring Security Authorization server with `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`. With this I could customize the token endpoint in order to receive an additional parameter in the token endpoint (with the support of this [Spring OAuth2 Generate Access Token per request to the Token Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020702/spring-oauth2-generate-access-token-per-request-to-the-token-endpoint)).

I achieved this by implementing the `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` interface. In this implementation I designed the authorization server to issue tokens based on the user credentials (username and password) and on an additional parameter.

Is there a way to customize this new spring authorization server in order to receive an additional parameter when using the **client_credentials** grant_type, i.e. receive in the token endpoint the grant_type, client_id, client_secret and an additional parameter and issue an access token associated to these three elements?

Until now I've created a `CustomAuthenticationConverter` implementing `AuthenticationConverter`, and a `CustomOAuth2AccessTokenGenerator` implementing `OAuth2TokenGenerator<OAuth2AccessToken>`.

Is this the right path to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to propagate the additional parameter received in the token endpoint request by configuring an `accessTokenRequestConverter`. With this I obtain the additional parameter from the HTTP request (POST to the token endpoint) and I propagate it until including it in the token itself. Beyond the `accessTokenRequestConverter`, I also configured an `authenticationProvider` and finally a `CustomTokenGenerator`. I pass the additional parameter through the first two, and then I include it in the token, when the generation occurs in the `CustomTokenGenerator`.